# Weka: Convert Nominal to Numeric

Tags: weka, numeric

When I imported a CSvfile in Weka, it reads some numeric variable as Nominal Type. I would like to convert them to Numeric but Im not seeing any option in Weka.

I tried to open the .arff file using Notepad and Notepad++. I remove the variables and change it to numeric

example:

```
@attribute thours {' ',18,4,48,42,56,35,40,30,14,54,24,36,20,77,25,70,0,16,34,60,64,21,32,6,84,23,31,52,28,50,66,45,12,10,33,11,22,98,8,3,65,72,9,26,15,63,5,27,51,39,105,7,2,58,43,90,68,46,44,47,112,49,91,37,1,41,104,78,96,75,74,62,71,76,89,13,38,19,29,59,92,81,55,57,53,67,80,102,100,17}
```

to
     @attribute thours numeric

and save the file. when i imprted the fiel again, Im getting an error

```
"...not recognized as an 'Arff data files' file. reason: numebr expected, read Token ], line 78"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Dixi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I believe the reason for your error is that one or more entries of the variable, "thours", is missing.**  This is represented in the attribute description as the single quotes.  If those values are indeed supposed to be missing, you should change it to the format Weka expects in a ".arff", which is a question mark "?".

This [link](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html) provides a very detailed description of ".arff" files, and what is expected in them.

Comment: Thanks! Info about the arff file helps! :-D